# Is there a way to read in multiple files from multiple subfolders using a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to read in multiple .mat files in R. I want to iterate over multiple subfolders and pull all .mat files from each of them.

Previously, I've used the following code to do this, but as I gather more data, this method has become unruly.

```
#SUB001
library(R.matlab)
base :: setwd('filepath')
filenames <- base::list.files(
  path = ("filepath"), 
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "*.mat"
)
d <- lapply(filenames, function(x) readMat(x))
print(d)

#SUB002
library(R.matlab)
base :: setwd("filepath")
filenames <- base::list.files(
  path = ("filepath"), 
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "*.mat"
)
d <- lapply(filenames, function(x) readMat(x))

#SUB003
library(R.matlab)
base :: setwd("filepath")
filenames <- base::list.files(
  path = ("filepath"),
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "*.mat"
)
d <- lapply(filenames, function(x) readMat(x))
```

I'm trying to put together a for loop based on this code, and this is what I have put togther so far. It doesn't seem to work, but am I on the right track?

```
library(R.matlab)
for (i in file){
   base :: setwd("filepath")
   filenames <- base::list.files(
   path = ("filepath"),
   recursive = TRUE,
   pattern = "*.mat"
  )
 d <- lapply(filenames, function(x) readMat(x))
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Error in for (i in file) { : invalid for() loop sequence
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 for "list of tables", working patterns for this type of problem. (1) `for` loops return nothing, yo uare overriding `d` each pass through the loop, discarding the previous values. (2) You have an iteration variable `i` but never use it, reading the full list of filenames each time.

Comment: Ahhhh this helped SO much- thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, the `invalid for() loop sequence` happens when `file` (as you've used it here) is the ***function*** `base::file`. The `for` iterator does not know what to do with a function, similarly `for (i in mean) ...`.